I'm Trying to install FirebaseDatabase and FirebaseStorage with cocopods with Xcode 14.2
I'm installed FirebaseCore and FirebaseAuth to my project and Now I want to install FirebaseDatabase and FirebaseStorage in my application with Cocopods and I can not , I'm using [pod 'FirebaseDatabase' and pod 'FirebaseStorage'] in Podfiles then pod install in terminal , I used Xcode 14.2 version so I don't know if that version is the reason to can not install or not
[!] Error installing FirebaseAuthInterop
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git /var/folders/wd/krph3zg50ms9zj11x_jpd9b00000gn/T/d20240629-9977-ze2sgt --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch CocoaPods-10.28.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/wd/krph3zg50ms9zj11x_jpd9b00000gn/T/d20240629-9977-ze2sgt'...
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 5234 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I'm trying to install FirebaseDatabase and FirebaseStorage But I Cann't install

Can you include the Podfile. Might help your cause,  we have no idea what we are looking at here. Thanks!

The error message you encountered suggests there might be a network issue or a problem with the connection to the GitHub repository.

This does not answer your question, but I strongly recommend not using cocoapods. Firebase is available as a swift package.

Cocoapods works well and we use it every day for projects. We also find it's a bit easier to maintain and customize. Please include your podfile, version of cocoapods (pod --version). Also how did you install Cocoapods? via HomeBrew? You  may also need to do a pod repo update
